# Update web application in IIS using appcmd.exe

Tags: iis, web-applications, continuous-integration, appcmd

I am working in the continuous integration for a couple of projects using TFS2017 and I have a problem with the deployment. When I am creating the application in the corresponding website in IIS. I am using this commands in the appcmd.exe:

```
add app /site.name:MySite /path:/app1 /physicalPath:"C:\MyFolder\MySite\app1"
```

But the problem is when APP1 it's already created and the command line add app doesn't overwrite the initial app. Instead the ideal behavior that produces an error about an already created application.

My question is if exist some parameter that I can use in the command for force the overwrite that I need.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just delete the old site before creating the new one? That's what I do.

```
appcmd.exe delete site %SITE_NAME% >nul 2>&1
```

Comment: The problem with that is when I have to create for first time. Because I have to create a lot of application and I am trying to make a generic process and avoid change the code in the TFS.

Comment: Actually right now I am working on create a powershell script that check if the virtual directory of the application exist, and if exist delete the application, and create again the same. But I really like he idea about some command just for update.

Comment: You can attempt to delete the site if even if it does not exist - it will just do nothing. So you attempt to delete, then install, and that's all you need.